# Rails gem for receiving notifications when there's an error present in logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

Is there a gem that I could use which will notify me whenever there's an error present in my logs? It seems counterintuitive for one to have to scroll top to bottom in your terminal logs in order to locate an error and the exact line in your application of that error. Is there something that one can use that neatly displays all instances of errors and the exact location in ones application where those errors are occurring?

Answer (score 2):

Try this https://github.com/rails/exception_notification. 
Or this https://airbrake.io/pages/home (but it's not free).
Also to for better dev 500 error pages try https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors